# Change IIS Express SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, xamarin, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-signalr

I am developing .Net Core 2.1 Web App and a Xamarin Android app that communicate with each other using SignalR. When running the web app on my machine I need to change the app url from localhost to 127.0.0.1 so I can access it from the android emulator.

The issue is that when i change the url IIS express still uses the localhost certificate and SignalR doesn't trust the site and cant connect to hub. I have created a self signed certificate for 127.0.0.1, but IIS doesn't use that one.

Is there a way to force IIS express to use specific certificate? Or can i redirect 127.0.0.1 request to go to localhost instead?

Comment: Use Jexus Manager and then you can visually edit the site binding https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/getting-started/features.html

Comment: I suggest you use straight up Kestrel for the dev stage you're at.  Configuring a certificate will be a lot easier.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I am struggling at the same point and hosting hubs on azure for dev stage is not practical...